# Не проходит проверка на наличие в списке

Tags: python, python-3.x

Добрый день! есть код, пример:

```
import requests
import time
ignore = []
def work():
    global ignore
    while True:
        if site in ignore:
              pass
        else:
             r = requests.get ('mysite.com')
             if r.text == 'какое то значение':
                ignore.append('mysite.com')
             else:
                pass
```

Код работает прекрасно, но даже если mysite.com уже был, и занесен в список ignore- программа все равно посылает запрос. что я делаю не так?

Comment: Может заменить `requests.get('mysite.com')` на `requests.get(site)`

Comment: @diraria там итак в переменной, mysite.com просто для примера

Comment: Тогда приведите, пожалуйста, реальный код, в приведённом коде вроде проблем не наблюдается

Comment: @diraria он почти идентичен примеру, в том то и дело, что я тоже не вижу ошибки, список ignore успешно пополняется отработанными url, но функция все равно проверяет их по второму, третьему итд разу

Comment: Возможно в `r.text` проблема?

Comment: добавьте `print('...')` с различным текстом в каждую ветку `if ... else ...` (должно получиться 3 или 4 `print(...)`) - это поможет вам отладить ваш код... Мне кажется у вас будет бесконечный цикл в котором будет выполняться `pass`